# Where does IntelliJ IDEA deploy my freshly built .ear artifact?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, deployment, ear

I just recently switched from Eclipse to Intellij IDEA.
On Eclipse, as I deploy my ear artifact, it will deploy in WildFly's directory `standalone/deployments/`

However, in IntelliJ IDEA that folder remains empty and somehow IDEA is deploying an older version of the ear file, even though I just built a new one. How to manually force IDEA to deploy the ear I just built with maven? Also, where are those deployed ear-files located?

Thank you.

Comment: It might help to show your "Edit Configuration"

Answer (score 0):

Too see where your artifact is, go to File > Project Structure > Artifacts > YOUR_ARTIFACT > Output directory.

You're most probably using the "Deploy" action in Run/Debug tool window, which basically connects to the WildFly using JMX and triggers (via JMX) deploy command while passing to it the path to your artifact. You will most probably not find it in any WildFly folder, except maybe some temp folder.

Also, you said you've "built" a new one. Note that building the sources and building the artifact are two completely different things in IDEA.

I suggest you to do the following:

1. Compile/Make the module/project (Build > Make Project, or Build > Make Module, etc.)
2. Rebuild the artifact (Build > Build Artifacts > Rebuild). Note that this step can be auto-triggered on compilation (File > Project Structure > Artifacts > YOUR_ARTIFACT > Build on make);
3. Doublecheck that the ear located in the output directory (see File > Project Structure > Artifacts > YOUR_ARTIFACT > Output directory) has been just updated.
4. Trigger redeploy with "Deploy" action in Run/Debug tool window.

I will later update the answer with other methods of deployment, but I hope that 
the written so far will help.